# View Orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, orientation

Update: I found why it was loading the same view the whole time. I now fixed that. It was a typo

ControllerForSplitViews.m

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ControllerForSplitViews" bundle:nil];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        self.view = landscapeView;
    }
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        self.view = portraintView;
    }
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
    return self;
}
```

This works.

Now the problem. When the view is loaded and running I change the orientation and load a different view from the same nib file, Fixed: but as soon as I do this the other UI elements disappears and only the ui elements of my landscape view is kept and when I rotate the device again it doesn't load my portrait view again? Any suggestions why this might happen?

```
-(void) orientationChanged:(id)object
{   
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.view = portraintView;
    }
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.view = landscapeView;
    }
 }
```

New Problem, each time I change the orientation it loads the opposite orientation's view

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a fix that works, but I have no idea why my original code didn't work what I did was:

Remove:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Remove:

```
-(void) orientationChanged:(id)object
{   
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.view = portraintView;
    }
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.view = landscapeView;
    }
 }
```

Change:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
    (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))){

        self.view = landscapeView;

    }else if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || 
          (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))){

        self.view = portraintView;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

And now it works perfectly

Comment: Your example uses UIViewController class. So, what about UIViewControllerRotation category for all UIViewControllers? There several methods for rotating such as: - `(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;`

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this here as well for incase someone ever reads this, they might want to check out this post here where a simular scenario was discussed

[Two views Multiple UIPickerViews Single outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704357/two-views-multiple-uipickerviews-single-outlet)