# Two views Multiple UIPickerViews Single outlet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have two views for my app depending on what orientation it decides which view to load. But IB wont allow me to connect two PickerViews to the same OUTLET, is there a way to assign connections in code, so that when I load my view I assign the connections to the outlet?

Or should I do everything double for each view?

Or should I split my two views into different nib files

Please assit me in this

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, bear in mind that an IBOutlet is simply a property that has been declared in a way that makes it visible in IB.  So the answer to your first question is yes.  You can always reassign that property in code if necessary.

I presume you already have two IBOutlets for your landscape and portrait views -- something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;
```

And it sounds like you're selecting the appropriate view in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.

Similarly you could declare two outlets for your picker views:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *landscapePickerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *portraitPickerView;
```

If you go this route, I'd declare a dynamic property that always returns the picker view for the current orientation.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UIPickerView *pickerView;
```

Rather than synthesizing this property, you could implement it like this:

```
- (UIPickerView *) pickerView {
    if (self.landscapeView.superview) {
        return self.landscapePickerView;
    }
    else {
        return self.portraitPickerView;
    }
}
```

However, if you have more than one or two subviews, having parallel properties like this cluttering your controller could get to be a pain.  In that case, I'd consider making a custom subclass of UIView called something like PickerContainer that has outlets for your pickerView and any other subviews you need to access.  Then in IB you can change the classes of your landscape and portrait views to PickerContainer, and you can connect each picker directly to its superview.  Then in your controller you can just create one dynamic property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) PickerContainer *pickerContainer;

- (PickerContainer *)pickerContainer {
    return (PickerContainer *)self.view;
}
```

and after that you can access your pickerView for the current orientation via its container like this:

```
[self.pickerContainer.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

---

EDIT: Here's how I implemented `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` on one of my projects:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        if (self.landscapeView.superview) [self.landscapeView removeFromSuperview];
        self.portraitView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                               self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
        [self.view addSubview:self.portraitView];
    }
    else {
        if (self.portraitView.superview) [self.portraitView removeFromSuperview];
        self.landscapeView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                                self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
        [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView];
    }
}
```

My landscape and portrait views were configured with no struts or springs in IB, meaning all the margins are flexible, but the width and height aren't.

Comment: I did as you suggested. But now when I want to load this view it freezes and then after a while it gives me an exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. the code i use there is: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        self.view = landscapeView;
        
    }
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        self.view = portraintView;
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: Don't swap the views out in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.  That method should do nothing except return YES.  Instead, swap the views in `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`, and base your conditional on its `toInterfaceOrientation` parameter.

Comment: Sorry... I actually meant to tell you to swap the views in `- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`.  I get those mixed up.  I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrient‌​ation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`  when I paste this method into my code it says Expected method body, even though I did add the implementation and the same for `- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfac‌​eOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

Comment: Never mind I found the problem with that method, now I have something very weird happening, when I change the orientation it loads the opposite view, for instance when I change to landscape it loads landscape but shows portrait? Any idea why this is happening

Comment: I had this problem before and what I did was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689325/view-orientation-changes now it doesn't animate the new view to rotate, any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm...  I just went back and looked at an old project where I defined landscape and portrait views in the same xib.  In that project I didn't actually swap out self.view.  Instead I made self.view a wrapper view, and I added and removed the landscape and portrait views as subviews of that wrapper.  Sorry, I hope I didn't confuse you.  I shouldn't post this stuff from memory.  I'll paste my willAnimate... method directly into my answer above.

Comment: I assume doing it your way will have at animate nicely. So I tried adding in the init method `self = [super initWithNibName:@"ControllerForSplitViews" bundle:nil];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        [self.view addSubview:landscapeView];
    }
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        [self.view addSubview:portraintView];
    }
    return self;` but then it just freezes... or shall I say it stops responding

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to do that in init.  Referencing self.view immediately triggers the lazy loading of the view from the nib.  You don't want this to happen during your init.  Move that code to `viewWillAppear:`.  Also make sure you remove any existing subview first.

Comment: @Armand let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1505/discussion-between-cduhn-and-armand)

Comment: I moved it but I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS `0x327e5dd2  <+0010>  str r3, [sp, #8]` here

Comment: When you have time can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730044/uipickerview-not-returning-the-correct-data

Answer (score -1):

I recently applied this concept in my application. What you can do in such a case is to assign an **int** to each button which displays the picker on touch.
Say you have two buttons *btn1 and btn2*. Let their touch actions are *btn1Action* and *btn2Action*. You can also have a single toolbar for both pickers. Set visibility of picker and toolbar as hidden in xib.

```
-(void)btn1Action:(id)sender
{
picker.setHidden = NO;
toolbar.setHidden = NO;
iPicker = 1;          // Declared globally
}  

-(void)btn2Action:(id)sender
{
picker.setHidden = NO;
toolbar.setHidden = NO;
iPicker = 2;          // Declared globally
}  

-(void)toolbarAction:(id)sender
{
picker.setHidden = YES;
toolbar.setHidden = YES;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{



     if(iPicker==1)
    {
      return 10;
    }
     if(iPicker == 2)
    {
        return 8;
    }


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{

    return 1;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)iComponent
{

     if(iPicker==1)
    {
   // Your code

   }
    else if(iPicker == 2)
    {
        // Your code
    }


}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)iComponent
{

    else if(iPicker == 1)
    {
         // Your code

    }
    else if (iPicker == 2)
    {
        // Your code
    }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above code can still be minimised by assigning tags to the button and then you can have a single action. `-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender { picker.setHidden = NO; toolbar.setHidden = NO; iPicker = sender.tag; // Declared globally }`