# UIPickerVeiw multiple orientations return correct picker of loaded view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Ok here is my problem. I have a view that loads another view as subView when the device rotates. This is working perfectly. Now my problem is that I have a PickerView on each orientation's view that has outlets assigned to them, the why I implemented is as was suggested here: [Two views Multiple UIPickerViews Single outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704357/two-views-multiple-uipickerviews-single-outlet) The problem I am having is that when I populate my PickerViews the data is not being pulled through.

```
if(pickerView == pickerType) {
    return [myHelper.types objectAtIndex:row];
}else if(pickerView == pickerTown){
    return [myHelper.towns objectAtIndex:row]; 
}else
{
    return @"";
}
```

As I understand that when I do this code:

```
- (UIPickerView *) pickerTown
{
    if(self.landscapeView.superview)
    {
        return self.landscapePickerTown;
    }else
    {
        return self.portraitPickerTown;
    }
}
```

I will be able to access the picker on the correct view. But for some reason it is not working, I might be doing some thing wrong. Please help.

Comment: check your connections with the file's owner are made or not and also the delegates of uipickerview.

Comment: @robin Ok my connections are made, I have checked that. It might be the following though, pickerFrom is a wrapper for portraitPickerFrom and landscapePickerFrom but there is no outlets assigned to it. I believe this is correct as when I access pickerFrom it needs to return the outlet of the current view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the best approach but when adding data do the following

```
if(pickerView == landscapePickerType || pickerView == portraitPickerType) {
    return [myHelper.types count];   
}else if(pickerView == landscapePickerTown || pickerView == portraitPickerTown){
    return [myHelper.towns count];
}else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Regards